# Service has leaked ServiceConnection that was originally bound here

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am using a BraodCastReceiver that starts an IntentService. Everythings look working good, but I get this error which I don't know its source:

```
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service     com.merchantech.app.smartdiscount.MyIntentService has leaked ServiceConnection  com.clover.sdk.v3.order.OrderConnector@535008f4 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1426)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1415)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.clover.sdk.v1.ServiceConnector.connect(ServiceConnector.java:119)
        at com.clover.sdk.v1.ServiceConnector.waitForConnection(ServiceConnector.java:148)
        at com.clover.sdk.v1.ServiceConnector.execute(ServiceConnector.java:209)
        at com.clover.sdk.v3.order.OrderConnector.getOrder(OrderConnector.java:153)
        at com.merchantech.app.smartdiscount.MyIntentService.onHandleIntent(MyIntentService.java:41)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Here's my BrodcastReceiver class:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals("com.test.intent.action.LINE_ITEM_ADDED")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my IntentService class:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        orderItem.addLineItem(orderId, lineItemId, var);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like some issue with your SDK. Please check whether it is making any service connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**:

The problem is due to the Clover SDK. They have not unbind a service that was bounded somewhere in the com.clover.sdk.v3.order.OrderConnector Class. So the problem is not relevant to the code snippet above.

Comment: The app wasn't crashing because of that error, so I left it as it was. Maybe, owners of Clover SDK have fixed this problem. I didn't check if they did or not. Hope I helped

Comment: I also have the same issue & i could not find a solution to it, let me check and update weather updating to latest clover sdk will fix this ?

Comment: @HiddenDroid did you find any solution to it ?

Comment: @HiddenDroid Still throwing same error with v293?, Any work around ?

Answer (score 9):

The error message basically means that some component  created a binding to a `Service` and did not unbind from the service before the component was destroyed.

You will need to provide more information about your app's structure to get a better answer to your question.  I'll make some guesses, and maybe give you some ideas about things to explore.

I'm guessing that you are using a library from Clover and maybe also Merchantech. Or maybe the Clover library uses a Merchantech library.  I'm also guessing that `orderItem` is an instance of a class defined by Clover, not you.

The Android runtime destroys an `IntentService` after `onHandleIntent()` completes and there are no more Intent requests queued.  You can confirm this by adding the `onDestroy()` method to your `MyIntentService` with a Log command to show when it is called.  That means that in the code you posted for `onHandleIntent()`, your IntentService will be destroyed soon after the call to `addLineItem()` completes.

The stack trace suggests that the processing triggered by the call to `orderItem.addLineItem()` causes a binding to another service.  Somewhere, that binding is not being managed properly--maybe not unbound when it should be.  Is there something the Clover subsystem expects you do to "close" it or "release" resources when your component (Service or Activity) is being destroyed?

Comment: As I know, no. But I will check.